# Index for join within a SQL ETL batch process

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, etl

Suppose I have a CTAS in a batch ETL process, with a join like this:

```
-- SQL Server syntax
SELECT *
INTO output
FROM input1 JOIN input2 on (input1.join_column = input2.join_column)

-- Everyone else
CREATE TABLE output AS 
SELECT *
FROM input1 JOIN input2 on (input1.join_column = input2.join_column)
```

Is there any benefit to having an index (clustered or otherwise) on either `input1.join_column` or `input2.join_column` if I expect to hit every row in both tables?

My impression was indexes were mostly helpful with a selective predicate -- i.e., to help you get to a small subset set of rows quickly.  But I'm wondering if there is any fringe benefit of having joins when you're doing an ETL-like operation.

My question is primarily for SQL Server, but I would be interested in knowing the answer for PostgreSQL as well.

Comment: Did you create the indexes and benchmark the performance? Runtime? Reads?

Answer (score 2):

An index will probably help, but it depends.

Databases have a bunch of different ways to handle joins:

- Nested loops (looping through one table then through the other).
- Nest loops with index (looping through one table and looking up the values in the other).
- Sorting the tables and merging.
- Using an index to sort the tables and merge.
- Hashing.

(And variations on these an more!)

What the optimizer chooses depends on the capabilities of the database, the hardware, the data, and the statistics.

That said, for this type of `join`, the second method is quite common and has good performance if both tables fit in memory.  The processing is basically looping through one table and looking up the appropriate values in the other, using an index.

Hashing and merging (without an index) both require reading and writing the data for intermediate data structures.  That can slow down the algorithms in practice -- even if the theoretical performance is better.

So, yes, an index can be quite useful for these types of queries.